# Whats the difference when i put the simple imputer on fit or transform def?

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to understand what the methods `fit` and `transform` do, but the tutorials from YouTube and GPT are both in an opposite way. I want to create a pipeline but I don't know whether `SimpleImputer` should be coded inside the defintion of `fit` or `transform`.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

class FeatureImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, strategy='mean'):
        self.strategy = strategy

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy=self.strategy)
        self.imputer.fit(X)
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        return self.imputer.transform(X)
```

I tried asking gpt but it just keep saying that imputer should be put on fit, can someone explain it ???

Comment: It's not clear to me what "imputer should be use on fit" or "imputer should be put at tarnsform" mean.  And why are you wrapping `SimpleImputer` into this custom class instead of just using it directly?